# SearchKit - tag more than one contact

Tags: searchkit

Can anyone give me an idea where this error is coming from and how I could fix it?

https://speicher.dienstleistungskombinat.de/s/w6YWHL9gYwqibwY

LG
Gregor

Comment: Can you check drupal logs to get more details about the error?

Comment: Hi Gregor. I find it a really useful self-help tool to reconstruct the simplest possible comparably SK on one of the master sites eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ and confirm if the problem exists. i did this with a v simple SearchKit and could not replicate a problem. at that point the questions that come up are 1/ how does your version number compare to dmaster 2/ can you do any changes to the version on dmaster to match your search that does then cause the problem, if so it can be reported on gitlab as an bur

Comment: i also tried adding some Tags that were not just for Contacts, eg for Activities, but those did not show in the dropdown (good), and ones for Contacts AND Activities did show, and did work.

Comment: you may also want to install the logviewer extension if you don't already have, as it gives easy access to civi logs https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.logviewer

Comment: Thank you for your tips and ideas. I found out that the error occurs as soon as I want to assign an existing tag again. In this case it rejects the request altogether. Also on dmaster.
It would be helpful to know this in the error message or if only the contacts that have not yet been tagged would be tagged.
Would you agree and how can I pass this on to whom?